# Cannot find module 'firefox-profile' in protractor

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor

I have provided the snapshot of console, where i am getting error as "cannot find module Firefox-profile, which is causing the failure in loading the run-tests file.

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZqIR.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have q and firefox-profile modules installed:

```
npm install q firefox-profile --save-dev
```

Hope it will help you :)